# CentOS 7 minimal doesn’t get an IP address

Tags: networking, centos-7

I have created a small closed cluster system running on centos 7 minimal and not connected to outside. I have connected all the nodes via a switch.

On startup, node gets IP but a couple of seconds later disconnects. I struggle to make it have the IP again by restarting either the network or doing `ifup enp4s0`. Sometimes I repeat this process maybe for 10 minutes so that it can get the IP assigned in the following config file.

Is there a way to fix this issue so that machine can have IP automatically?

Below is the output of the ethernet interface file `ifcfg-enp4s0`.

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
PROXY_METHOD="none"
BROWSER_ONLY="no"
BOOTPROTO="none"
#DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
#IPV6INIT="yes"
#IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
#IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
#IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
#IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
NAME="enp4s0"
UUID="1fe7b71d-5b84-40af-a9e7-958188cf0d91"
DEVICE="enp4s0"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR=192.168.1.105
KEY_MGMT="IEEE8021X"
#IEEE_8021X_EAP_METHODS="TTLS"
#IEEE_8021X_IDENTITY="I removed intenionally"
#IEEE_8021X_ANON_IDENTITY="I removed intenionally"
#IEEE_8021X_INNER_AUTH_METHODS="PAP"
#IPV6_PRIVACY="no"
```

Comment: You are assigning it a static ip address, one reason it would be kicked off the network, is some other device on the network had the same address.  Is that the case?

Comment: No, it is not the case as it is a closed system and not open to the outside world. Also, It will not have the same address with other nodes in my system because I assigned a different static IP by hand for all other nodes.

Comment: Check `journalctl -r` and find the exact moment the issue occurs.

Comment: Any reason why you didn't define the `NETMASK` and `GATEWAY` directives?

Comment: @nKn Not intentionally actually. The default config file does not include Netmask or Gateway lines, that's why I did not modify or add them.